# C++ convert string to int

Tags: c++, c++11

Used stoi() method to convert string to int, but it converts to int even when there is alpahabet.

```
string str1 = "45";
string str2 = "31337 test"; 

int myint1 = stoi(str1); // 45
int myint2 = stoi(str2); // 31337
```

str2 is converted to int, but I don't want this convertion since it has alphabet. If there any way to catch or prevent this conversion.

Comment: If you **read the documentation** for `std::stoi` you might find something useful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can check the number of characters processed.

```
string str2 = "31337 test"; 
std::size_t num;

int myint2 = stoi(str2, &num); // 31337
//                      ^^^^

// num (the number of characters processed) would be 5
if (num != str2.length()) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the streams functionality to read a number and make sure there is nothing else on the stream.

```
std::string        str = "31337 test"; 
std::stringstream  stream(str);

int   val;
char  x;
if ((stream >> val) && !(stream >> x)) {
    // We read an integer from the stream.
    // **and** there is nothing else on the stream
    // (except white space)
}
```

Useful as you can also use it with any particular base:

```
if ((stream >> std::setbase(8) >> val) && !(stream >> x)) {
    // We read an integer from the stream.
    // **and** there is nothing else on the stream
    // (except white space)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [stoi reference page](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/stoi/)

```
string str2 = "31337 test"; 
string::size_type sz;   // alias of size_t
int myint2 = stoi(str2,&sz);
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you don't want conversion to happen if other than numbers present in string.

in that case, you can use below

```
int convertOnlyWhenNumbersPresentInString( std::string str ){

    if (std::all_of( str.begin(), str.end(), ::isdigit ))
    {
        return std::stoi( str );

    } else
    {
        return -1;
    }  
}

int main() 
{

    std::string str1 = "45";
    std::string str2 = "31337 test";

    std::cout << convertOnlyWhenNumbersPresentInString( str1 ) << std::endl; // prints 45
    std::cout << convertOnlyWhenNumbersPresentInString( str2 ) << std::endl; // prints -1
}
```